# Issues with running PublishFromPublishingQueue extension

Tags: gui-extensions

I just added the PublishFromPublishingQueue extension on SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1.

It did provide the context menu option but when I select something to publish, it does not put any item on the queue. I would have expected it to pop up the publish dialog to allow me to select my options.

Did I do something wrong in setting it up?

Here is what I changed in the `system.config` file, as instructed

```xml
  ...
  <editor name="PublishFromPublishingQueue"> 
    <installpath>E:\Tridion\Extensions\PublishFromPublishingQueue</installpath> 
    <configuration>Configuration\PublishFromPublishingQueue.config</configuration> 
    <vdir>PublishFromPublishingQueue</vdir> 
  </editor>
</editors>
```

And here is the setup in IIS:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just did a quick test myself, which worked fine, so let me quickly recap what I did, hopefully that helps you in tracing back what you might have missed.

1. downloaded the extension from [SDL Tridion World](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/publishfrompublishingqueue.aspx)
2. opened the zip and copied the `Extension\PublishFromPublishingQueue` directory on my CM server
3. in IIS added a virtual directory for the extension
4. adjusted the `System.config` under `%TridionHome%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration` to contain the following fragment:

```xml
<editor name="PublishFromPublishingQueue">
  <installpath>C:\Extension\PublishFromPublishingQueue</installpath>
  <configuration>Configuration\PublishFromPublishingQueue.config</configuration>
  <vdir>PublishFromPublishingQueue</vdir>
</editor>
```

5. increased the `modification` attribute on the `server` node in `System.config`
6. refreshed my browser

It worked fine for me this way on 2013 SP1 HR1, with the one remark that the icons on the context menu were incorrect (because the extension still pointed to the icons from 2013 GA), use the following in your `Themes\Carbon\Publishing.css` for 2013 SP1 HR1:

```css
#cm_pq_publish.item .image
{
  /* 2013 SP1 icons */
  background-image: url({ThemePath['CME']}/Sprites/cme_Sprites.16px_v7.1.0.66.8_.png);
  background-position: 0 -624px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}

#cm_pq_unpublish.item .image
{
  /* 2013 SP1 icons */
  background-image: url({ThemePath['CME']}/Sprites/cme_Sprites.16px_v7.1.0.66.8_.png);
  background-position: 0px -640px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}
```

From what information you gave, it should have worked, that all looks fine. If you still have an issue, you might want to take a look in the browser console, and see if there are any errors logged in there when it tries to load the scripts or open the dialog.

Apart from not clearing the cache (by increasing the `modification` attribute), the only other thing I could thing of being a problem, is access from IIS to the content in the virtual directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reloading or opening/closing the browser.  If that does not helps, do the below:

Modify the `system.config` under `%TridionHome%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration`
 to increment the modification attribute

```
<server version="7.1.0.66" modification="16">
```

Comment: Edited the answer since @Bart completely revamped the question and added screenshot and configuration details